# PopUp alert message using Event receiver in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created event receiver with C# coding in SharePoint.when item should match is already have. it showing massage like this is my code..

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);  
            SPList oList = null;
            string strCarName = string.Empty;
            using (SPWeb web = properties.Web)
            {
                oList = web.Lists["Cars"];
                string dropdwnvalue = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["CarName"].InternalName;
                String lookupFieldStringValue = Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties[dropdwnvalue]);
                SPListItem item = oList.Items[Convert.ToInt32(lookupFieldStringValue) - 1];
                strCarName = Convert.ToString(item["LinkTitle"]);
            }
            string strStartdate = Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties["EventDate"]);
            SPQuery existingItemsQuery = new SPQuery();
            existingItemsQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + strStartdate + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Car_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + strCarName + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection existingItems = properties.List.GetItems(existingItemsQuery);


                if (existingItems.Count >= 1)
                {

                    properties.Cancel = true;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "Item is already exists";
                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "test", "<script>alert('Hello');return false;</script>"); 
                }
```

output:-

item is already exists.
that item adding only one time in a day.again i cant add another item. But i want add another item in a day change time

any one can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you have problem with the query string, you should use this:

```
existingItemsQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + strStartdate + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Car_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + strCarName + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```

and you should have strStartdate with format like this '1971-01-01T00:00:00Z'

you can use this method:

```
SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["EventDate"])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' will compare time value in your datetime field

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can register script because the page will be redirected. 
But you can use `properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl` and add custom parameter to query string. Also script must be always on the page. 
So you just check necessary parameter in QS and show alert if it is present.